# how to parse multiple elements for a particular value

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I am receiving a string of XML from a web service and am parsing it to pick up a few values that I need to save. I am putting the string into an XmlDocument  and using the XmlNodeReader to parse the element name and grab the value.

This is fine apart when the value I am after is named, such as Type, ID or source in this snippet:

```
<WebResult>
    <Header>
      <Type>Success</Type>
      <ID>52347</ID>
    </Header>
  <Source>Global</Source>
   <ReturnItems>
    <ReturnItem>
      <DataName>SaleID</DataName>
      <DataValue>CO12345</DataValue>
    </ReturnItem>
    <ReturnItem>
      <DataName>ProductID</DataName>
      <DataValue>XY000001</DataValue>
    </ReturnItem>
  </ReturnItems>
</WebResult>
```

However, I'm not sure of the best way to pickup the SalesID's 'DataValue' value of CO12345 in this example. (The XML schema is much larger)

I could parse the string for the SaleID + x characters but that would break if the web service changed and I am relying on string positions. I would prefer not have to serialize into a class as it seems there should be a simple way to do this. (which I am missing!)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), if you're able to (or willing to) use it.

```vb
' XDocument.Parse will load XML from a string
' Use XDocument.Load to load it from a file
Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)

Dim salesID = (From x In xDoc.Descendants("ReturnItem")
              Where x.Element("DataName").Value = "SaleID"
              Select x.Element("DataValue").Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

What the above code snippet does is first gets all the "ReturnItem" elements (and their children) in `xDoc`.

Next, it filters it on "DataName" elements that have SalesID as the value.

Then it selects the corresponding "DataValue" element's value.

`FirstOrDefault` returns the first element that matches (or the default value if nothing is found).  Without `FirstOrDefault()` you would get a collection of matching results that you could then iterate through.

The above is a pretty trivial example, but LINQ to XML is very powerful and I prefer it when dealing with XML.

**EDITED TO ADD NON-LINQ APPROACH**

Here's a way to do the above using [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and [XPath syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx):

```vb
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
' Use LoadXML to load from a string; if from a file use Load
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString)

Dim SaleID As String

Dim ReturnItems As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/WebResult/ReturnItems/ReturnItem")

For Each Item As XmlNode In ReturnItems
    If Item.SelectSingleNode("DataName").InnerText = "SaleID" Then
        SaleID = Item.SelectSingleNode("DataValue").InnerText
    End If
Next
```

The above snippet of code loads the XML string into an `XmlDocument`.  Then, it selects all the nodes that match the XPath expression "/WebResult/ReturnItems/ReturnItem" (i.e., it grabs all the ReturnItem nodes and their children).

Next, it iterates through the collection, and for each ReturnItem node, it checks to see if the DataName node is equal to "SaleID", and if it is it then assigns the value of the DataValue node to the `SaleID` string.

This is, again, a trivial example.  If you have multiple "SaleID" nodes in the XML you'll need to put the values in a list or other collection, otherwise the above code will give you only the last one.

XPath is very powerful, and rich support for XML and XPath has been a part of the .NET Framework since 1.0.

The advantage here is that if the format of the message ever changes, you'll only need to update your XPath queries, rather than figuring out how to parse the new format.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Linq is definitely the way to go but for reasons outside of our control we are stuck with NET Framework 2.0 for this project. (Framework is incompatible with Linq without some hacks.)

Comment: @SSJON - Take a look at `XmlDocument` and XPath queries.  I've posted a trivial example above to give you a basic idea.